# why isn't my jQuery working when I try to fetch a tag by Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I'm trying to fetch and listen to an event on form tag by id, but the jQuery isn't working and I got no errors...

```js
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('connected to server');
});


socket.on('newMessage', function(data) {
  console.log('message', data);
});

socket.on('changeParagraph', function(data) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = data
});

console.log('jQuery:', jQuery("#message-form"));

jQuery("#message-form").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  socket.emit('createMessage', {
    from: 'User Q',
    msg: 'test message!'
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chat App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="/js/libs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/index.js">
  </script>

  <h1>Welcome to the chat app! :)</h1>
  <form id="message-form">
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
    <button type="submit">send message</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

what am I missing here the console.log(jQuery('#message-form')) return a really big object like

> w.fn.init {} **proto**: Object(0)

and a bunch of other stuff in it... but not the form that I want...

what am I missing here??

thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: What does `console.log('jQuery:', jQuery("#message-form").length);` log?

Comment: You need to move your script to the bottom of the `<body>` or wrap the code in a [`$( document ).ready()` event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).  The problem with your current code is that the element does not yet exist when the selector code is run.

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: io is not defined",`

Comment: thank you jmoerdyk! I changed the order it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @jmoerdyk mentioned, you need to run your jQuery selector after the form has been defined, either by including your code at the bottom of the body tag or wrapping your jquery in the ready handler, like:

```js
jQuery(function($) { // runs onready, aliases jQuery as '$' in this func
  $("#message-form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    socket.emit('createMessage', {
      from: 'User Q',
      msg: 'test message!'
    });
  });
});
```

what you are seeing in your console log is the entire jQuery object, even though it didn't match any elements.

Comment: thank you derelict it worked! I just got started learning html and jQuery I didn't imagine that the order mattered that much!

Comment: hey lucas, not so much about the word as _when the code runs_ -- the way you had it, the code was running but the message-form wasn't actually defined yet -- using jquery's [onready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) ensures your jquery doesn't run until all the document has been loaded :)